# How to fix Minecraft 1.12 Null pointer exception error with entities?

Tags: java, entity, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I've been trying to fix it for ages, im stumped, everytime i open it it crashes with the same error message "java.lang.NullPointerException", heres the full error message:

```
net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoaderExceptionModCrash: Caught exception from The Human Tools Mod (sword)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.registry.EntityRegistry.doModEntityRegistration(EntityRegistry.java:207)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.registry.EntityRegistry.registerModEntity(EntityRegistry.java:192)
    at com.example.examplemod.init.EntityInit.registerEntity(EntityInit.java:18)
    at com.example.examplemod.init.EntityInit.registerEntities(EntityInit.java:13)
    at com.example.examplemod.util.handlers.RegistryHandler.preInitRegistries(RegistryHandler.java:62)
    at com.example.examplemod.util.ExampleMod.preInit(ExampleMod.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.FMLModContainer.handleModStateEvent(FMLModContainer.java:626)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber.invokeSubscriberMethod(Subscriber.java:91)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber$SynchronizedSubscriber.invokeSubscriberMethod(Subscriber.java:150)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber$1.run(Subscriber.java:76)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:399)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber.dispatchEvent(Subscriber.java:71)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Dispatcher$PerThreadQueuedDispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:116)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:217)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.sendEventToModContainer(LoadController.java:218)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.propogateStateMessage(LoadController.java:196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber.invokeSubscriberMethod(Subscriber.java:91)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber$SynchronizedSubscriber.invokeSubscriberMethod(Subscriber.java:150)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber$1.run(Subscriber.java:76)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:399)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber.dispatchEvent(Subscriber.java:71)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Dispatcher$PerThreadQueuedDispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:116)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:217)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.distributeStateMessage(LoadController.java:135)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Loader.preinitializeMods(Loader.java:627)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.client.FMLClientHandler.beginMinecraftLoading(FMLClientHandler.java:252)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.init(Minecraft.java:513)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:421)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:118)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraftforge.gradle.GradleStartCommon.launch(GradleStartCommon.java:97)
    at GradleStart.main(GradleStart.java:25)**
```

as well as some of my code:

the code that is trying to register the entity:

```
public class EntityInit
{
    public static void registerEntities()
    {
        registerEntity("human", EntityHuman.class, ExampleMod.ENTITY_HUMAN, 50, 3093151, 16287108);
    }

    private static void registerEntity(String name, Class<? extends Entity> entity, int id, int range, int color1, int color2 )
    {
        EntityRegistry.registerModEntity(new ResourceLocation("sword:" + name), entity, name, id, ExampleMod.instance, range, 1, true, color1, color2);
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesnt say there is any issues in the code, it just crashes when trying to run it

Comment: I've no clue about minecraft API, but I recommend you to use a debugger.

Comment: I think your mod itself is registered incorrectly. Can you post your ExampleMod.java?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I debugged it and found it to be caused by what I assume is a version mismatch between class net.minecraftforge.fml.common.network.NetworkRegistry and enum net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.Side.

Side has 3 values but the NetworkRegistry code appears to assume there are only 2, CLIENT and SERVER.

I fixed this by taking a copy of the NetworkRegistry class, and editing it as follows:

In the private, parameterless constructor, add the following line:

```
channels.put(Side.BUKKIT, Maps.<String,FMLEmbeddedChannel>newConcurrentMap());
```

[Code change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgB5K.png)

Then you just need to make sure that your version of the class in on the classpath before the original version (if you're using eclipse then it will be automatically). You also need to make sure that you use the exact same package name for your version of the class.